# Wide ball stumping off last ball

Tags: rules, officiating, cricket

Last ball, last wicket, 1 run required for the batting side to win the match. Bowler bowls a wide ball and the batsman gets stumped as well.

Which team will win considering the given situation?

Answer (score 10):

In the said case, the batting side wins by 1 wicket. The last stumping will not count as the match is completed and the ball is dead as soon as the wide is bowled.

I do not know of any match that has ended in this wide-stumping scenario. But in this [India vs Sri Lanka](http://www.espncricinfo.com/sl-tri2010/engine/match/456663.html?innings=2;page=1;view=commentary) game, India needed 1 run to win with the batsman needing 1 run to complete his century. The bowler bowls a no-ball and the batsman hits a 6. The six however does not count as the match ends as soon as the no-ball was bowled and the batsman is left stranded on 99.

> **34.4**. Randiv to Sehwag, 1 no ball, match is over, but Sehwag has been denied the century. And this is a big no-ball, must I point out? His
>   back foot was close to over-steeping, forget about the front foot.
>   Anyway Sehwag smashed it for six over long-off, but they don't count
>   because the game finishes at no-ball. He raises his arms, but then
>   realises the century is not completed.

Answer (score 3):

The call of the wide ball results in one run as extras and thereby the team achieves the required run to win. It should be understood that the wide ball, though called when the ball crosses the wickets at the striker's end, is deemed to have been a wide from the time the ball leaves the hand of the bowler. Hence, the stumping is not counted.

Answer (score 2):

Since the wide ball occurs first the batting side will win because the match is considered finished after the wide ball is delivered.

Almost same situation occurred in the match between [Sri Lanka vs India](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2134/540) where team required 1 run to win and batsman was on 99 and he hit a six but it was not considered in his account since the team was won by no ball.

Answer (score 1):

Wide ball will earn 1 run for batting side and they will win. This is same situation in which a batsman runs out in a no ball. But his team will earn 1 run for the no ball.Won't consider whether batsman is out or not

Answer (score -3):

This should not be the case. If one run is needed and one wicket left and bowler bowls a wide and batsman gets out stamped on the same ball. Result is one run added to batting team and simultaneously losing the last wicket. A team has to win by at least wicket when the match is over.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, please include a reference to your answer. Your answer seems as opinion to me.

Comment: No, the two events do not occur simultaneously; the Laws are *very* clear on this: the wide is deemed to have occurred when the ball left the bowler's hand (Law 25.3(a)) and the stumping clearly occurs after that. Hence the match is over (Law 21.6(a)) and the fact that the wicket was broken is irrelevant.