# What will the batsman score from a winning boundary with one run needed to win?

Tags: rules, cricket, scoring

Assume a team needs 1 run to win and the batsman needs 2 or more runs for his century or half century. The batsman then plays a shot completes his first run then the ball goes to the boundary or six.

How is the score written? Did the batsmen score a half century or a century or did they win the match when the batsmen completed his first run? What was the batsman score of this delivery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the batsman get runs on No ball when the team requires only 1 run to win?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/does-the-batsman-get-runs-on-no-ball-when-the-team-requires-only-1-run-to-win)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of that answer since it refers to a no-ball. Related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the laws of cricket allow running on the last ball even after winning?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/do-the-laws-of-cricket-allow-running-on-the-last-ball-even-after-winning?).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Law 16](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-16-the-result/)...

> 16.6.1 As soon as a result is reached as defined in 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4 or 16.5.1, the match is at an end. Nothing that happens thereafter, except as in Law 41.18.2 (Penalty runs), shall be regarded as part of it.  Note also 16.9.

also

> 16.6.3 If a boundary is scored before the batsmen have completed sufficient runs to win the match, the whole of the boundary allowance shall be credited to the side’s total and, in the case of a hit by the bat, to the striker’s score.

So basically once the batsmen complete the first run (which is the only run required to win) then the match ends. If the ball goes to the boundary then that won't count, and therefore the batsman will only be credited 1 run not 4.

However if the ball goes to the boundary before they complete the first run then 4 runs will be given to the batsman (and the team score also), since once it reaches the boundary the match ends.